# Average TIME in SSRS give me more number (00:20:21.333333)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

[Average in SSRS give me more number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EY3Xq.png)

hay I need to do Average on time in ssrs 
my expr is

**=TimeSpan.FromTicks(Avg(TimeSpan.FromTicks(Avg(Fields!datediffnew.Value))))**

tanks,
ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to apply "format" to an actual TIME datatype. But it seems to me, that SSRS does not work with TIME in appropriate way. You may try to add DATE to your TIME and then apply "format" to the result.

So, expression would be:

```
=Today +  TimeSpan.FromTicks(Avg(TimeSpan.FromTicks(Avg(Fields!datediffnew.Value))))
```

Then go to Textbox properties => Format

```
hh:mm:ss
```

Comment: it does not work :( , ERROR MESSAGE - The Value expression for the text box ‘Textbox45’ refers to the field ‘CurrentTime_AS_TIME’.  Report item expressions can only refer to fields within the current dataset scope or, if inside an aggregate, the specified dataset scope. Letters in the names of fields must use the correct case.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to see .33333

Textbox properties => Format, type this => `hh:mm:ss`

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you have wanted to do:

=TimeSpan.FromTicks(Avg(Fields!datediffnew.Value))